# All possible combinations with varying lengths

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinations

Hey I have an array of numbers:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I need to find every combination of then numbers with varying lengths:

```
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
.
.
.
[1,2,3,4,5,8]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

**NOTE**: it does not matter what order the numbers are inside the array.

I want be pass the arrays to a function inside a loop so varying sized vectors should not be a worry.

I have tried perms() inside a loop however it returns far too many results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should expect 2^8 results. how many did `perms` returned to you?

Comment: perms([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); resulted in 40320 combinations for ONE length (length = 8;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick to generate all variable-size combinations with `nchoosek`: introduce `0` to represent "no number" (assuming your numbers are never 0). That will generate duplicates, so you need to apply `unique` to the rows of the resulting matrix. Finally, remove zeros from each row and store the results into a cell array:

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; %// data

n = numel(v);
vz = [zeros(1,n-1) v]; %// add n-1 zeros to represent the absence of a number
r = nchoosek(vz,n); %// generate combinations, one in each row
r = unique(r,'rows'); %// remove duplicate rows
result = arrayfun(@(k) nonzeros(r(k,:)).', 1:size(r,1), 'uni',0); %'// delete 0's
```

Comment: That is a nice way to avoid a loop! But I think OP wants permutations and not combinations.

Comment: @hkf I don't think it's permutations the OP wants, is it? They are all in increasing order in the example

Comment: hmm I guess OP should clarify that in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Works perfectly, it was just combinations i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has this function NCHOOSEK for combinations, but this is for a fixed size only. So, we were needed to run this through a loop of varying sizes.

Code:

```
v=1:8;
for k = 1:numel(v)-1  
    in1 = nchoosek(v,k+1);
    your_func(in1);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want permutations you will need to run perm on the results from nchoosek. Martrix S has combination results and matrix P below has the permutation result:

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
S ={};
for ii =1:length(v);
    S{ii} = nchoosek(v,ii);
end
P={};
for kk = 1:length(S)
    data = S{kk};
    for jj = 1:size(data,1)
        P{jj} = perms(data(jj,:));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your array. I don't know much about matlab, but [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) claims the following as an [implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#MATLAB) of the algorithm, and it looks okay to me:

```
function pset = powerset(theSet)

    pset = cell(size(theSet)); %Preallocate memory

    %Generate all numbers from 0 to 2^(num elements of the set)-1
    for i = ( 0:(2^numel(theSet))-1 )

        %Convert i into binary, convert each digit in binary to a boolean
        %and store that array of booleans
        indicies = logical(bitget( i,(1:numel(theSet)) )); 

        %Use the array of booleans to extract the members of the original
        %set, and store the set containing these members in the powerset
        pset(i+1) = {theSet(indicies)};

    end

end
```